# JTable : How to change, add new record link text? (mvc 4.0)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

How to change default `+Add New Record` link Text in J-Table?

Comment: please mark my answer as the correct answer for others

Answer (score 8):

Direct from the author of JTable, it's by far the best way to accomplish this.

```
 $('#MyTableContainer').jtable({

    messages: {
        addNewRecord: 'Add new whatever'
    },

    actions: {
        //Action definitions comes here
    },

    fields: {
        //Field definitions comes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out jTable's Localization feature, though specifically used for different languages, you can easily take advantage of this feature and create a new localization.js file for your project. This way you can always update to the latest version of jTable without worrying about changes that you might have made to the core jTable.js library files. You should never directly change core third party libraries that you reference in a project because you will always reach the time when you must upgrade to get the latest new features or hotfixes for your third party library assets and you will be stuck in a tough position because you will not remember exactly what you changed nor how to transfer your changes to the latest version.

http://www.jtable.org/apireference#Localization

So in my project, I have a jTable that loads a "Job" datatype. So I simple created a custom directory and file called jquery.table.jobs.js within /Scripts/jtable/localization directory, this is as good as place as any but you could put your extended message(s) js files anywhere. This is the code in jquery.table.jobs.js:

```
/*
    jTable localization file for jobs grid
*/
(function ($) {

    $.extend(true, $.hik.jtable.prototype.options.messages, {
        serverCommunicationError: 'An error occured while communicating to the server.',
        loadingMessage: 'Loading jobs...',
        noDataAvailable: 'No data available!',
        addNewRecord: 'Add New Job',
        editRecord: 'Edit Job',
        areYouSure: 'Are you sure?',
        deleteConfirmation: 'This job will be deleted. Are you sure?',
        save: 'Save Job',
        saving: 'Saving Job',
        cancel: 'Cancel',
        deleteText: 'Delete Job',
        deleting: 'Deleting Job',
        error: 'Error',
        close: 'Close',
        cannotLoadOptionsFor: 'Can not load options for field {0}',
        pagingInfo: 'Showing {0}-{1} of {2} Jobs',
        pageSizeChangeLabel: 'Row count',
        gotoPageLabel: 'Go to page',
        canNotDeletedRecords: 'Can not deleted {0} of {1} records!',
        deleteProggress: 'Deleted {0} of {1} records, processing...'
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Hopefully you are using Bundling and Minification features as am I so I just added to my BundleConfig.cs class:

```
   //====================================================================
            //Add jtable localization bundles for Customer messages for each type of data being managed by a jTable
            //====================================================================
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jtable-custom-messages-jobs").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jtable/localization/custom/jquery.jtable.jobs.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jtable-custom-messages-customers").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/jtable/localization/custom/jquery.jtable.customers.js"));
            //====================================================================
```

And then in my Job view I simply add:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jtable-custom-messages-jobs");
```

And of course in my customer view that has a jTable that loads "Customer" type data records, I add:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jtable-custom-messages-customers");
```

Where bundle jquery-customer-messages-customers is just bundling of another jTable localization override script: /Scripts/jtable/localization/jquery.jtable.customers.js which contains specific messages like "Add New Customer" instead of "Add New Job".

Answer (score 0):

Open jquery.jtable.js (or even the minified version), ctrl + f, and search for "add new record" to find the property in the file.  Then change it to whatever you want to display.

Comment: That is a quick and dirty, there is a better way.

Comment: Old post but still worth mentioning to new devs - An update to JTable or even a re-installation thereof would make your changes undone. Not clever. jTable provided for this customization already as per Brian's post.